# Getting ftp data with RCurl

Tags: r, ftp, rcurl

I can access ftp site with Chrome but not with Internet Explorer cause of company restriction I think. For that reason maybe, I can not download ftp data with RCurl in R. Do you have any solution to download ftp data via Chrome setup in R?
Thanks

```
url<-c("myUrl")
x<-getURL(url,userpwd="user:password", connecttimeout=60)
writeLines(x, "Append.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `RCurl` does not use a web browser to access ftp sites. It uses `libcurl`, as it says in the documentation. The problem you encounter should be solved within the constraints of `libcurl`.

Also, if one web browser on your computer can access a website, and another can't, it need not be a problem with the web browser per se. The most common problem is the way files or paths are referenced, such as whether or not one includes a trailing `/` with a pathname (never with a filename, of course). Perhaps this is the case for you?

Otherwise there may be a problem with your `ftp` settings: `libcurl` is pretty smart about guessing things right, but it is possible to twiddle with all sorts of settings, in case the defaults do not work, for example (from the manual):

```
  # Deal with newlines as \n or \r\n. (BDR)
  # Or alternatively, instruct libcurl to change \n's to \r\n's for us with crlf = TRUE
  # filenames = getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, ftplistonly = TRUE, crlf = TRUE)
```

filenames = paste(url, strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]], sep = "")
   con = getCurlHandle( ftp.use.epsv = FALSE)

If this doesn't help, it might help us help you if you give us more complete information. What is this `myUrl` in `url<-c("myUrl")`, for example? Is it a filename? A pathname?